# Ambiguous type variable error msg

Tags: haskell, type-inference, typeclass

I don't think it is a bug, but I am a bit puzzled as to why that doesn't work. A bonus question is why does it mention variable e? There is no variable e.

```
    Prelude> :m +Control.Exception
    Prelude Control.Exception> handle (\_-> return "err") undefined

    <interactive>:1:0:
        Ambiguous type variable `e' in the constraint:
          `Exception e'
            arising from a use of `handle' at <interactive>:1:0-35
        Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Prelude Control.Exception>
```

Apparently it works fine in ghci 6.8, I am using 6.10.1.

Edit: I have minimized the code. I expect that to have the same result in both 6.8 and 6.10

```
class C a                                                                                                     

foo :: C a => (a -> Int)-> Int                                                                                
foo _ = 1                                                                                                     

arg :: C a => a -> Int                                                                                        
arg _ = 2                                                                                                     

bar :: Int                                                                                                    
bar = foo arg
```

trying to compile it:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /tmp/foo.hs, interpreted )

/tmp/foo.hs:12:10:
    Ambiguous type variable `a' in the constraint:
      `C a' arising from a use of `arg' at /tmp/foo.hs:12:10-12
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude Control.Exception>
```

Answer (score 13):

The type of `Control.Exception.handle` is:

```
handle :: Exception e => (e -> IO a) -> IO a -> IO a
```

The problem you are seeing is that the lambda expression `(\_ -> return "err")` is not of type `e -> IO a` where `e` is an instance of `Exception`.  Clear as mud?  Good.  Now I'll provide a solution which should actually be useful :)

It just so happens in your case that `e` should be `Control.Exception.ErrorCall` since `undefined` uses `error` which throws `ErrorCall` (an instance of `Exception`).

To handle uses of `undefined` you can define something like `handleError`:

```
handleError :: (ErrorCall -> IO a) -> IO a -> IO a
handleError = handle
```

It's essentially an alias `Control.Exception.handle` with `e` fixed as `ErrorCall` which is what `error` throws.

It looks like this when run in **GHCi 7.4.1**:

```
ghci> handleError (\_ -> return "err") undefined
"err"
```

To handle all exceptions a `handleAll` function can be written as follows:

```
handleAll :: (SomeException -> IO a) -> IO a -> IO a
handleAll = handle
```

Catching all exceptions has consequences described well in this excerpt of the `Control.Exception` documentation:

> ## Catching all exceptions
>
> It is possible to catch all exceptions, by using the type `SomeException`:
>
> ```
> catch f (\e -> ... (e :: SomeException) ...)
> ```
>
> HOWEVER, this is normally not what you want to do!
>
> For example, suppose you want to read a file, but if it doesn't exist then continue as if it contained `""`. You might be tempted to just catch all exceptions and return `""` in the handler. However, this has all sorts of undesirable consequences. For example, if the user presses control-C at just the right moment then the `UserInterrupt` exception will be caught, and the program will continue running under the belief that the file contains `""`. Similarly, if another thread tries to kill the thread reading the file then the `ThreadKilled` exception will be ignored.
>
> Instead, you should only catch exactly the exceptions that you really want. In this case, this would likely be more specific than even "any IO exception"; a permissions error would likely also want to be handled differently. Instead, you would probably want something like:
>
> ```
>  e <- tryJust (guard . isDoesNotExistError) (readFile f)
>  let str = either (const "") id e
> ```
>
> There are occassions when you really do need to catch any sort of exception. However, in most cases this is just so you can do some cleaning up; you aren't actually interested in the exception itself. For example, if you open a file then you want to close it again, whether processing the file executes normally or throws an exception. However, in these cases you can use functions like `bracket`, `finally` and `onException`, which never actually pass you the exception, but just call the cleanup functions at the appropriate points.
>
> But sometimes you really do need to catch any exception, and actually see what the exception is. One example is at the very top-level of a program, you may wish to catch any exception, print it to a logfile or the screen, and then exit gracefully. For these cases, you can use `catch` (or one of the other exception-catching functions) with the `SomeException` type.

**Source: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Exception.html#g:4**

Answer (score 10):

This problem shows up only in GHC 6.10; it can't be duplicated in GHC 6.8 because the type of `handle` is different:

```
: nr@homedog 620 ; ghci
GHCi, version 6.8.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :m +Control.Exception
Prelude Control.Exception>  handle (\_ -> return "err") undefined
"err"
Prelude Control.Exception>
```

---

OK maybe I can get this right at last.  I think the problem is *not* the monomorphism restriction, but rather you've hit an instance of the Read/Show problem: you're offering to handle some type of exception, in the new version of `handle, there is more than one type of exception, and the type of that exception does not appear in your result.  So the compiler has no way of knowing *which* type of exception you're trying to handle. One way to work this is to pick one.  Here's some code that works:

```
Prelude Control.Exception> let alwaysError :: SomeException -> IO String; alwaysError = \_ -> return "err"
Prelude Control.Exception> handle alwaysError undefined
"err"
```

Incidentally, the example use of `handle` in the GHC library documentation does not compile under 6.10.  I have filed a bug report.

Comment: Why does the compiler need to know which exception? The function handles every type from the class.

Comment: Because of the type of `handle`; any use of `handle` must be applied to *one* particular type from the Exception class.  Since your handler works for all types in the class, there's no way for the compiler to assign a type to `handle`.  (The `e` comes from the type of `handle`.)

Comment: If you use the ScopedTypeVariables extension you can just do 'handle (\(_ :: SomeException) -> return "err") undefined'.

Comment: @Porges, that no longer works :( Illegal result type signature `IOException'
      Result signatures are no longer supported in pattern matches

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is to use `Control.OldException` in ghc 6.10.* instead of `Control.Exception`.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving your handler the type `SomeException -> IO x`, where x is a concrete type, e.g.

```
import Control.Exception
let f _ = putStrLn "error" :: SomeException -> IO () 
in handle f undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

"Exception e" is likely from the type signature of "handle".

[The documentation](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Exception.html#v:handle)
says:

```
handle :: Exception e => (e -> IO a) -> IO a -> IO a
```

In GHC 6.8 it used to be different, which would explain why I don't get that error.

```
handle :: (Exception -> IO a) -> IO a -> IO a
```

Seems you're running into the monomorphism restriction. That "_"-Pattern must be monomorphic (which it is with ghc 6.8) or explicitly typed. A "workaround" is to put the pattern on the left hand side of a definition, where it constitutes a "simple pattern binding" as specified by the Haskell Report.

Try this:

```
let f _ = return "err"
handle f undefined
```

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction

Comment: let f _ = return "err"
handle f undefined

gives the same error

Comment: How about the pragma
{-# -XNoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

Comment: I think it's {-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}