# GHC compilation error arising from import of Control.Exception

Tags: types, haskell

Continuing roadblocks when trying to learn Haskell.

I am following the "Real World Haskell" and when it comes to getting one of their complex examples to work, I obtain the following error

"Ambiguous type variable `e' in the constraint:`
GHC.Exception.Exception e'
        arising from a use of `handle' at FoldDir.hs:88:14-61
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)"

My relevant bits of code are:

```
import Control.Exception (bracket, handle)
maybeIO :: IO a -> IO (Maybe a)
maybeIO act = handle (\_ -> return Nothing) (Just `liftM` act)
```

How do I eradicate this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431527/ambiguous-type-variable-error-msg

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to specify a type for the handler-function's argument, so it knows which kinds of exceptions to handle.

You can either do this by naming the function

```
import Control.Exception (handle, SomeException)
maybeIO act = handle handler (Just `liftM` act)
    where handler :: SomeException -> IO (Maybe a)
          handler _ = return Nothing
```

Or by using the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Control.Exception (handle, SomeException)
maybeIO act = handle (\(_ :: SomeException) -> return Nothing) (Just `liftM` act)
```

Comment: This provides me both with an answer, and helps in my attempts to learn and understand Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

`Control.Exception` exposes a different interface in GHC 6.10 and later. For a quick fix, change

```
import Control.Exception (bracket, handle)
```

to

```
import Control.OldException (bracket, handle)
```

Answer (score 1):

Control.OldException is deprecated. With extensible exceptions, one needs to specify a type for the exception, even if it is never used. My version of maybeIO is

```
perhaps ∷ forall a. IO a → IO (Maybe a)
perhaps task = do
  result ← (try ∷ IO a → IO (Either IOException a)) task
  return $ either (const Nothing) Just result
```

One needs the explicit `forall` to bring the type variable `a` into scope, and the GHC compiler flag `-XExplicitForAll` to use the explicit `forall`. One cannot give `try` a type out in the open without getting the error *"You cannot give a type signature for an imported value."* If one tries the type declaration elsewhere, e.g. on the result of `try task` then GHC can't sort it out. So yes, this is a bit embarrassing for us strong typing advocates, but it gets better.