# Haskell Error: "Ambiguous type variable" in Exception.catch; Need type signature, but where?

Tags: exception, haskell, types

I am trying to convert my program's error handling to use exceptions.  I built a REPL to control my simulation where I also handle errors:

```
> repl :: Sim -> IO Sim
> repl old_sim = do
>     new_sim <- E.catch (do line <- getLine
>                            commands <- parseCommand line
>                            runCommands commands old_sim)
>                        (\err -> do putStrLn . show $ err
>                                    return old_sim)
>     if alive new_sim
>        then repl new_sim
>        else return new_sim
```

Either parseCommands or runCommands may `fail String`, both of which return `IO Sim`.

When I load the file, I get this giant error:

```
Prelude> :l simple_sim
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( simple_sim.lhs, interpreted )

simple_sim.lhs:95:18:
    Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraints:
      (E.Exception a0) arising from a use of `E.catch'
                       at simple_sim.lhs:95:18-24
      (Show a0) arising from a use of `show' at simple_sim.lhs:100:49-52
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression:
        new_sim <- E.catch
                     (do { line <- getLine;
                           commands <- parseCommand line;
                           runCommands commands old_sim })
                     (\ err
                        -> do { putStrLn . show $ err;
                            return old_sim })
    In the expression:
      do { new_sim <- E.catch
                        (do { line <- getLine;
                              commands <- parseCommand line;
                              runCommands commands old_sim })
                        (\ err
                           -> do { putStrLn . show $ err;
                               .... });
           if alive new_sim then repl new_sim else return new_sim }
    In an equation for `repl':
        repl old_sim
          = do { new_sim <- E.catch
                              (do { line <- getLine;
                                    commands <- parseCommand line;
                                    .... })
                              (\ err -> do { ... });
                 if alive new_sim then repl new_sim else return new_sim }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Specifically:

```
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

Where would I insert this type signature?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431527/ambiguous-type-variable-error-msg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need it on err to determine which exceptions you are trying to catch.

Comment: But if I add it as (\err ::E.SomeException -> ...), I get "Illegal result type signature `E.SomeException', Result signatures are no longer supported in pattern matches"

Comment: You need to turn on some extension to be able to put type signatures in the lambda.  But you can put it anywhere on err.  Or on the function itself.

Comment: Anm add a first line of `> {-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}`.

Comment: @Anm ah yes, as we just said on IRC use `(\(err :: E.SomeException) -> ...)`