# Haskell type error with catch

Tags: haskell, exception

I am playing with some online examples, and one has this phrase:

```
   do ... contents <- getDirectoryContents path `catch` const (return [])
```

But it won't compile for me, and gives the error:

```
No instance for (Exception e0) arising from a use of `catch'
The type variable `e0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Exception NestedAtomically
    -- Defined in `Control.Exception.Base'
  instance Exception NoMethodError
    -- Defined in `Control.Exception.Base'
  instance Exception NonTermination
    -- Defined in `Control.Exception.Base'
  ...plus 7 others
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  contents <- getDirectoryContents path `catch` const (return [])
In the expression:
  do { contents <- getDirectoryContents path
                   `catch` const (return []);
```

I had to change it to give a type for the handler, which is OK now but a bit messier:

```
contents <- getDirectoryContents path `catch` (\(SomeException e) -> const (return []) e)
```

So I am wondering why I needed to make this change, and if this is the most concise way to do it.
(Yes, I know I could use alternate forms of try, handle, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`catch` has type `Exception e => IO a -> (e -> IO a) -> IO a` so `(e -> IO a)` is where you are passing the `const` function result but the `const` return type in this case is `(e0 -> IO [])`. As you can see that this type has `e0` which is not constrained like it was required in catch i.e `e` should have `Exception` instance and thats what the error says.

So conceptually, you are passing something that is "less constrained" to a place where something "more constrained" is required.

Comment: so why couldn't it just unify the general type variable e0 with the polymorphic e in the catch type? and - why would it have worked in the original example?

Comment: @guthrie: It can unify, but GHC needs to know *which* concrete type it unified at, since the `Exception e` constraint will produce different behavior, depending.  It's like the ambiguity error you might get with `show undefined`; it's not sure which `show` function to use.

Comment: @Antal: It seems to me that this is a bit different, as show has a type constraint (Show a) which must be met to unify, but in this case the handler (const) is unconstrained, it can take any type, so could be unified with anything.

Comment: This is related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431527/ambiguous-type-variable-error-msg -where someone also comments that the type of handle changed between GHC 6.8 and 6.10, perhaps that is why this used to work in the original code.

Comment: @Ankur: thanks, yes, clear explanation. One might say "passing something more (too) general where something more specialized is required".

Comment: As for why you had to make this change, and why it would have worked in the original example: there are 2 different `catch` functions defined in the standard libraries, one in `System.IO.Error` and one in `Control.Exception. The online example you're using, which version does it use?